# How to pass specific JSON data from one factory to another factory in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, factory

I'm trying to build a simple Weather App using Angular JS.

I've created a -
1)Html Page
2)3 Angular Js components -

## CONTROLLER

```
angular
.module('weather')
.controller('weatherctrl', function($scope, factory,getGeoLoc){
    $scope.ip;
    $scope.geoloc;
//city obtainer-

        factory.getIP().success(function(data){
            $scope.ip = data;

        }).error(function(error){
            console.log("error");
        });

        //use the ip obtained on the lo/la api.

        getGeoLoc.getGeo().success(function(data){
            $scope.geoloc = data

        }).error(function(error){
            console.log("error");
        })
    });
```

## FACTORY 1 - Gets THE IP ADDRESS

```
//This is the factory for data recieving.

angular
.module('weather')
.factory('factory',function($http){function getIP(){
          return $http({
    method:'GET',
    url:'http://ip-api.com/json/'
})
} return {getIP:getIP} });
```

## FACTORY 2- *This is where I face problem*

*I've to pass the IP from the factory 1 to factory 2 to use the longitude and latitude*

```
angular
.module('weather')
.factory('getGeoLoc',function($http){

    function getGeo(data){
        return $http({
            method:'GET',
                url:'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat='+data.lat+'&lon='+data.lon+'&units=metric&APPID=0bd5e484b08e1c327c6bb917a530ad63',

        })


    }

    return{
        getGeo:getGeo
    }

});
```

I've tried passing/returning

```
getGeo(getIP)
```

as a function parameter towards getGeo in factory 2.But it doesn't work.

Please help me out, im a beginner at Angular JS.

Also the controller and both the factories are written on different *js* files.
controller.js
factory1.js
factory2.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both functions, `factory.getIp` and `getGeoLoc.getGeo`, return promises. To **chain** promises, **return** values or promises to the next.

```
   factory.getIp()
     .then(function getIpSuccess(response){
        $scope.ip = response.data;
        //return next promise to chain
        return getGeoLoc.getGeo($scope.ip);
   }).then(function getGeoSuccess(response) {
        $scope.geoloc = response.data;
        //return data for chaining
        return $scope.geoloc;
   }).catch(function onReject(error){
        console.log("error ", error.status);
        //throw to chain error
        throw error;
   });
```

In the above example if the `getIp` operation fails, the `getGeo` operation will be skipped. The catch handler will get either errors from the first or second `.then` handler.

**Avoid** the use of `.success` and `.error` because **they ignore return (or thrown) values**.

Instead **use `.then` and `.catch`**.

Comment: Code works exactly as I wanted. Will make sure I handle such responses properly next time!